# Cannot install ubuntu on new computer

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on my new computer. I have a MSI x570 board and a nvidea 2070 super. I already installed windows on one of my drives. 
I have disabled secure boot and my Secure Boot Mode is set to standard.

I can get grub but when I try to install it I get the error:

```
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

I replaced quiet splash tried to put

```
noapic noacpi nosplash
```

and I get this screen:
[output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqYPd.jpg)

Comment: Did you validate your ISO download? or write to install media?  It'd be my first step (but may not be your issue)

Comment: yes,  I plug into a different computer and was able to get into ubuntu.

Comment: Unless your other machine has identical hardware (thus the same exact packages were read) and you used the same menu options (thus the same packages again), booting on one machine is not a 100% valid test even if you scanned the logs for squashfs errors....  That's why the 'check disc for defects' option is there.  But you probably scanned your logs & did the checks...

Comment: @guiverc how do I do that? when I run  'check disc for defects'  I get the same error.

Comment: You can do the validation in either machine (*assuming no hardware issues apply which we hope doesn't apply) so I'd for sure validate the media in the other machine.  If 'check disc for defects' passes there, it's related to this box, and I'd start with standard diagnostics (ram tests/memtest86 etc)

Comment: i am able to boot into windows no problem and my BIOS show all my RAM/graphics card and disks mounted

Comment: BIOS only validates memory as being present (often 1 byte tested per 128KB) and windows kernel starts using/allocating ram from the opposite end to linux kernel - so it's a poor proof of perfect ram  (unless very thorough testing was performed or you have a small (<1gb) amount of ram)...

Comment: I cannot even get into check disk for defect. the screen shows a bunch of checks before show garbage. Could it be a graphics problem?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from MSI? AMD UEFI/BIOS update for Ryzen 3000 series
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good
AMD Releases BIOS Fix To Motherboard Partners For Booting Newer Linux Distributions July 2019
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Releases-Linux-Zen2-Fix For nVidia, you will need nomodeset boot parameter, and MSI often has needed other boot parameters or UEFI settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download a new ISO for Ubuntu, and validate the ISO before you generate the LiveUSB by [comparing checksums](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) ([alternate](https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/)).

To do that in Windows, use the [fciv](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290) app [freely available from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/windows-kb841290-x86-enu.exe), with the command `FCIV -sha256 path\ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` to compare against the value of the [SHA256 checksum](http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-iso/18.04.3/SHA256SUMS).  (Note: Canonical has a download glitch right now for the checksum, so an alternate 20G site, Princeton Mathematics, was used iinstead.)

Then, make the LiveUSB using a different USB drive, thereby eliminating the two most likely causes of your issue.